# Android Firebase complex join query

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Firebase structure

[image]

What code/query would produce the following result:

Get the museums , each museums exhibit , and each exhibits fields!

I tried nesting some queries with no avail, I'd appreciate any help!

Also if you think this is a wrong design please do propose a design that'd make this task easier or better in Firebase design terms.

Comment: For a single museum or for all museums?

Comment: could you maybe propose for both ?

Comment: @AlexMamo are you going to try give an aswer ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase structure would work well if your app flow is:

[Museum List View] -> User selects museum (Show Exhibit List View)

[Exhibit List View] -> User selects Exhibit (Show Exhibit Field List View)

[Field List View] -> User selects Field (Show Field Details)

From a code perspective, each step is a new call to Firebase to retrieve the appropriate information based on the user selection.  No join is necessary.

Comment: hmm , but if i wanted to show the exhibit and it's fields , i should do it with 2 queries that are not nested ? Wouldn't that be slower and not as effective as a join ?

Comment: Firebase is NoSQL and doesn't have a join function as such like SQL.  So yes, to create the table you would need to do a query for the list of exhibits and then for each exhibit do a query for the fields.

Comment: hmm ok ill try that and come back to you!